# How to use jodaTime with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jodatime

I want to use JodaTime LocalDate with hibernate. I wrote this:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "DATE_DEBUT", nullable = false)
@Type(type = "org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentLocalDate")
private LocalDate dateDebut;
```

but it didn't work. I get this error :

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7165] (Eclipse Persistence Services -   2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd):   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The type [class org.joda.time.LocalDate] for the attribute [dateDebut] on the entity class [class ch.test.application.beans.mandat.Mandat] is not a valid type for a temporal mapping. The attribute must be defined as java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar.
```

Do you know why ?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Hibernate and JodaTime are you using?  Show us the relevant portions of your Maven POM.

Comment: Do you realize you're not using Hibernate at all, but EclipseLink? EclipseLink won't bother with Hibernate types and annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Jadira](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jadira.usertype/usertype.core)

All you have to is add this as dependency and then anotae like this:

```
@Column
  @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
  private DateTime endTime;
```

For more info check their [website](http://jadira.sourceforge.net/).

There is another library that integrates Joda Time with Hibernate from Joda themselves. Here is the [link](http://www.joda.org/joda-time-hibernate/userguide.html). But personally I could not make it work for me.